# Excels Still Appear On Taskbar After Closing

Tags: excel, taskbar

I have this problem where whenever I open excel workbooks (multiple of them), and I close one of the excels, it will still appear in the taskbar. And it will only disappear after I close ALL the excels. Ive tried comparing the settings in the Options>General and Options>Advance with other PCs but theyre all the same.

And this only happens for my Excel and not other Office Tools (word,ppt,etc.)
Anyone knows why/how to solve this, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's literally how Windows works. As long as Excel is open, it should appear on the taskbar.

Comment: true that when excel is still opened, the workbooks will appear on the taskbar. but when we have closed the workbook, it shall only show on taskbar workbooks  that are still opened. curious